# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null - using JavaScript in WebViewX

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview

I am building widget in FlutterFlow using WebViewX, I use JavaScript inside WebViewX to hide part of the site I am showing. Below is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:webviewx/webviewx.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebView({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.bypass = false,
    this.horizontalScroll = false,
    this.verticalScroll = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool bypass;
  final bool horizontalScroll;
  final bool verticalScroll;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final String url;

  @override
  _MyWebViewState createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  late WebViewXController webviewController;
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    webviewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => WebViewX(
        key: webviewKey,
        width: widget.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: widget.height ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ignoreAllGestures: false,
        initialContent: widget.url,
            initialMediaPlaybackPolicy:
            AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.requireUserActionForAllMediaTypes,
        initialSourceType:
            widget.bypass ? SourceType.urlBypass : SourceType.url,
    
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) => webviewController = controller,
    
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                   webviewController.evalRawJavascript(
                       "document.getElementsByClassName('news-info')[0].style.display='none';"),     
                },
        
        webSpecificParams: const WebSpecificParams(
          webAllowFullscreenContent: true,
        ),
        mobileSpecificParams: MobileSpecificParams(
          debuggingEnabled: false,
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          mobileGestureRecognizers: {
            if (widget.verticalScroll)
              Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
              ),
            if (widget.horizontalScroll)
              Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer(),
              ),
          },
          androidEnableHybridComposition: true,
        ),
      );

  Key get webviewKey => Key(
        [
          widget.url,
          widget.width,
          widget.height,
          widget.bypass,
          widget.horizontalScroll,
          widget.verticalScroll,
        ].map((s) => s?.toString() ?? '').join(),
      );
}
```

Page loads just fine, but required div block is not hidden, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null. I checked loaded site page in WebViewX frame and there is no original DOM structure so no div named "news-info" is present, so JS cannot find it. My questions are:

1. Is it normal WebView behaviour not to keep original DOM?
2. I have seen guides on using JS inside WebView to hide part of the site loaded, what is wrong with my implementation? Do I call JS code on the right time, after page is finished? Or should I do this earlier?
3. If there is no mistakes in the code could it be FlutterFlow or WebViewX issues, as guides I have seen are about WebView?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days trying to find answer before posting here, but found in 5 minutes after posting. What a shame :)

So WebViewX implementation is able to inject some JS code if source type of URL you pass to WebViewX is defined as "urlBypass", while default is just "url". Added a line:

`initialSourceType: SourceType.urlBypass,`

and you are good to go.